# how to reset the filters in a datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am unable to clear the filters using the fnFilter().

Here is my HTML code :

```
<table id="todays _table>

               <thead>
                 <tr id="todays_search_input_feilds">
                     <td class="input_filter">
                        <input type="text" id="type" class="form-control search_events">
                    </td>
                    <td class="input_filter">
                        <input type="text" id="vendor " class="form-control search_events">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    </table>
```

And Here is my JQuery Code

```
$('#todays_table').dataTable().fnFilter('');
    oTable.fnClearTable();
```

I tried clearing using the following approach:

```
$('input[class="form-control search_events"]').val('');
```

But the problem with this is that, it is clearing the value but the data is not loading in the dataTable. It is loading only after i click on any of the filters

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**To reset custom filters**

If you're using custom filtering function as in [this example](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html), you need to clear controls involved before filtering and redrawing the table.

```
$('input.search_events').val('');
$('#todays_table').dataTable().fnDraw();
```

**To reset global search**

- jQuery DataTables 1.9+

  Call `fnFilter()` API method with empty string as a first argument to reset the global search and redraw the table.

  For example:

  ```
  $('#example').dataTable().fnFilter('');
  ```
- jQuery DataTables 1.10

  Call [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) API method with empty string as a first argument followed by call to [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) API method to reset the global search and redraw the table.

  For example:

  ```
  $('#example').DataTable().search('').draw();
  ```

Comment: Its throwing an error. Do you have any other solution.

Comment: @Onera, are you using jQuery DataTables 1.10 or 1.9? What error are you getting in the console?

Comment: I am getting error saying search is not a function, so i am its not datatables 1.10, i tried using your latest code - values are clearing but the datatable is not drawn, after i click on filter it is loading

Comment: If you are using custom filters, you can reset all the columns at once using: $('#yourtable').DataTable().columns().every( function () { this.search('')} );  
Then reset the global search and redraw the table: $('#yourtable').DataTable().search('').draw();

Answer (score 9):

> DataTables 1.10+ new API can achieve the same effect without the
>   requirement for plug-ins using the following chaining:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
```

If you are using earlier versions of DataTables, you need to include plugin library called *fnFilterClear* and call:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
table.fnFilterClear();
```

Please see this [DataTables API page](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnFilterClear) for more information and the plugin that needs to be used for earlier versions of DataTable.

Comment: The example given for DataTables 1.10+ doesn't work. If you order by column (e.g. column 2 descending) and then use it, it will return the results still ordered by column 2 descending, albeit without any of the search terms affecting the result. I use DataTables in Server Side mode but can't see any way to implement this where it resets the `sort` and `order` (to ASC, column 0) sent in the ajax request.

Comment: never knew you could stack them like this `table.search('').columns().search('').draw();`. this is the only case that works for me

Answer (score 7):

For those who's performing a search with **column** and **regex**:

```
$('#example').DataTable().column('').search('').draw();
```

Comment: column('') should be columns(''). $('#example').DataTable().columns('').search('').draw();

Comment: @Avnishalok the answer is specific for *column* and *regex*, as I said.

Answer (score 2):

I am using DataTables 1.10.15 and it is working for as below.

```
        var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
        $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.length = 0;
        oTable.draw();
```

Comment: that works for me but it doesn't reset the filter selections

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/api/fnFilterClear.js"></script>

  $.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
 fnInitComplete: function(oSettings, json) {
   var btnClear = $('#clear_all');
  btnClear.appendTo($('#' + oSettings.sTableId).parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_filter'));

  $('#clear_all').click(function () {
   $('#' + oSettings.sTableId).dataTable().fnFilterClear();
   $("input.column_filter").val('');

       $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
  });

 }

});
```

Comment: include the script file

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Here I have used the datatables API fnfilterclear  and called that API function to clear the values of the filter and side by side cleared the input fields of my filters . Here clear_all is my button id which I have initialised in my html to clear the filter

Answer (score 0):

DataTables 1.10+ new API

```
var D_T = $(selector).DataTable();
     D_T.
         search('').
         columns().search('').visible( true, true ).order('asc' ).
         colReorder.reset().
         page.len(10).
         state.clear().
         draw() ;
```